# Creating a column in a temp table with dynamic SQL and Cursor

Tags: sql-server-2008, cursor, dynamic-sql

I am using SQL Server 2008 and I am trying to create a temp table depending on the selection from user.

```
declare @x nvarchar(max), @mgchk int, @sgchk int, @ssgchk int, @seasonchk int, @vendorchk int, @storeid varchar(10), @trsfrom date, @trsto date

set @trsfrom = '1/1/12'
set @trsto = '1/1/13'
set @mgchk = 1
set @sgchk = 1
set @ssgchk = 1
set @seasonchk = 1
set @vendorchk = 1

set @x = 'create table ##aa ('

if @mgchk = 1
    set @x = @x + 'MainGroup varchar(20),'
if @sgchk = 1
    set @x = @x + 'SubGroup varchar(20),'
if @ssgchk = 1
    set @x = @x + 'SubSubGroup varchar(20),'
if @seasonchk = 1
    set @x = @x + 'Season varchar(20),'
if @vendorchk = 1
    set @x = @x + 'VendorID varchar(20),'

declare storecr Cursor scroll for
select distinct storeid from RPTrs where TRSDate between @trsfrom and @trsto
open storecr 
fetch next from storecr 
into @storeid 
while @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 begin
set @x = @x + @storeid + ' decimal(15,2),'
fetch next from storecr 
into @storeid 
end 
close storecr 
deallocate storecr

set @x = @x + 'Total decimal(15,2))'

execute sp_executesql @x

select * from ##aa
```

I get these errors when I run it though :

> *Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
>
>   Incorrect syntax near '01'.
>
>   Msg 208, Level 16, State 0, Line 47
>
>   Invalid object name '##aa'.*

Final output should be based on how many stores made transactions between the @trsfrom and @trsto date range. So if 3 stores made sales during that time, the result I am looking for is (the 01, 02 and 03 is store names):

```
MainGroup | SubGroup | SubSubGroup | Season | Vendor | 01 | 02 | 03 | Total
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
          |          |             |        |        |    |    |    |
```

The StoreID field in RPTrs is a varchar(5) if that is the issue. But the store columns will display the amount of the sales made between the date range.

Answer (score 0):

Figured out the problem. My set within the cursor was missing [ ]

```
set @x = @x + '[' + @storeid +']' + ' decimal(15,2),'
```

Comment: FYI, [`QUOTENAME()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176114.aspx) is the preferred (and easier) way to do that, because it can also handle delimiters inside the identifier name